# setPlaybackQuality() does not work anymore

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

setPlaybackQuality() does not work anymore, even on official YT Api Demo: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

What has changed in the work of the YouTube Iframe api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, finally, answer from Google:

> setPlaybackQuality is now considered a "no-op"; calling this function
>   will not change the player behavior. The player will use a variety of
>   signals to determine the optimal playback quality.
>
> Users are able to manually request a specific playback quality via the
>   quality selector in the player controls.

Answer (score 4):

You can read in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70440398#comment7) that the functionality is no longer supported, the method is still there, but as a no-op.

> due to changes in our player infrastructure, the player will no longer
>   honor requests to set a manual playback quality via the API. As
>   documented, the player has always made a "best effort" to respect the
>   requested quality.
>
> The documentation will be updated in the future to indicate this call
>   is no longer supported, though it will still be available as a "no-op"
>   for compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It was also reported in this [thread](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/2595). You could file a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)) if you think this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For those still interested, I tried `setPlaybackQualityRange()` as a drop-in replacement, and it works just fine.